# Android app, finish() doesn't work

Tags: android, activity-finish

The `finish()` method sends me back to the main activity, rather than terminating the app. Any suggestions?

Comment: finish() just kills the current activity. It does not terminate the app. Read the docs first.

Answer (score 3):

I guess it works, because `finish()` is not in any way intended to terminate app. There's no such concept on Android anyway. What `finish()` does is, as you see, terminate **activity**. [See docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#finish%28%29)

In general it usually helps to understand what you doing, so RTFM on "misbehaving" methods prior asking sounds like good habit to quickly solve most of "does not work" problems like this one.

There's SO's question you should follow as well: [Is quitting an application frowned upon?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2033914/quitting-an-application-is-that-frowned-upon)

Answer (score 0):

Finish terminates an activity, not an application. To terminate an application, call finish() on the entry activity that started it (thus clearing the stack).